# VS2017 SQL Server Database Project Cross Database Queries

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution that uses 2 databases.  I've created 2 SQL Server Database Projects within the solution.  1 for each DB.  I have 1 stored procedure and 1 view that references data from the other database.  When coding in the db you do something like Database1.dbo.table1 or Database2.dbo.Table2  The 2 databases always reside on the same server.  This is not a perfect solution because if the name of the database changes I've got to go in and change the sp/view to change the name, but it works.

However, in migrating these apps to use SQL Server Database projects for code review/management, the VS project doesn't recognize the other database so it flags it as an error.  What is the best way to implement this?  Is there a way to alias the database and then have the sql use the alias and it is recognized as valid?

Comment: My question would be why in the world are you changing the name of your database? That sounds like a truly awful design problem.

Comment: If we have a Dev Instance or a Test Instance on the same server.  We change the name and add Dev/Test to the end of the name.

Comment: That doesn't sound great to me. How can you ensure your code works when you have to change the queries before deployment? Have you considered using synonyms? You can't do that for the database but you can for the tables and other objects. If you do that then the same code just works in other environments because nothing has to change. The difference is in the synonym.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that.  So I tried it.  It resolves the issue of having to remember what sp/views are affected if I move/rename the db to have another instance.  I still have to recode synonyms but that is a heck of a lot easier to remember.  It did not fix the issue with the VS SQL Server Database Project.  Replacing my Database2.dbo.Table2 with synTable2 isn't recognized for some reason.